# Meteor app on digitalocean with https://app and https//www. Sometimes fails to serve https://app

Tags: meteor, digital-ocean, mup

### Problem:

My app runs on digitalocean droplet with multiple domains:

```
proxy: {
  domains: 'example.com,www.example.com',
  ssl: {
    letsEncryptEmail: '@'
  }
}
```

Sometimes, for about half an hour the https://example.com fails to load completely but indirect links like  https://example.com/about works fine.

### Tried:

fiddling with nginx option:

```
nginxServerConfig: './nginx.conf',
```

Any attempts with it failed loading page completely

### Mup.js file:

---

```
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {}
  },
  app: {
    deployCheckWaitTime: 300,
    name: 'example',
    path: '../',
    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },
    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'https://example.com',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb:27017/example',
    },
    docker: {
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base',
      args: ['--link=mongodb:mongodb'],
    },
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },
  proxy: {
    domains: 'example.com,www.example.com',
    ssl: {
      letsEncryptEmail: '@'
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: If nginx ist heavily involved, you may add the anonymized content of the `nginx.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that problem lied in mailgun.

The mailgun DNS records didn't match `v=spf1 include:eu.mailgun.org ~all` thus those mails weren't authorized and whenever mail was sent through the system it was tripping domain provider to refresh it's DNS.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting up a permanent redirect for www through my domain settings.